# How do I install pyCurl?

Tags: python, windows, installation, pycurl

I tried everything! I cannot find a way to install **pyCurl** on my Windows 7 machine!

I found these **binaries** [link](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/)... BUT there are no binaries for 2.6. : (

---

Help would be great. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [python2.6 binary](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/pycurl-ssl-7.19.0.win32-py2.6.exe) for pycurl [someone](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) compiled for that, and for [amd64](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/pycurl-ssl-7.19.0.win-amd64-py2.6.exe) also

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.woodpecker.org.cn/moin/PyCurl?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=pycurl-7.20.1.win32-py2.6.zip

and this is mine, with newer libcurl 7.20.1, openSSL 1.0.0, etc.